# Openid Connect standard way for exchanging ID Tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Is there any stadated way for replacing ID tokens of 2 authorization servers ?

For example, i have a service that you can login with an external ID Token but my service is also an authorization server and therefor i want to allow users exchange external ID Tokens with my service ID token.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth2 specification defines following grant types:

- authorization code
- implicit grant
- resource owner password credentials
- client credentials

But it also supports defining [additional grant types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-8.3) where required:

> New authorization grant types can be defined by assigning them a
> unique absolute URI for use with the "grant_type" parameter.

Per specification, new endpoints, parameters, response types and error codes may be defined to support the grant type extension.

When implemented, a client can make a request providing new grant type:

```
POST /token

grant_type=id_token&id_token=external-token&...
```

which would validate incoming token and issue your service's token.

Here are some links from oauth servers supporting custom grant types for inspiration:

- https://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/grants/custom_grant.html
- https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/writing-a-custom-oauth-2.0-grant-type/
- https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customGrantTypes.html